# Php header not working in function

Tags: php, phpmailer

here i am trying to send the mail from function and after the mail is sent i want to redirect page to index.php.

i am using php header to do so. but the header seems not to be working. if the mail has been successfully sent, then also the page remains same. it is not redirected to index.php

How can i do this?

```
<?php
   function sendInvitation($user_email,$invited_by)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
            if (defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
                $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
            }
            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
            $mail->IsMail();
        }
        $mail->From = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM;
        $mail->FromName = $invited_by;
        $mail->AddAddress($user_email);
        $mail->Subject = APP_INVITE;
        $link = INVITE_LINK;
        $mail->Body = $invited_by." ".FRIEND_INVITE." ".$link;
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_NOT_SENT . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;            
        } else {        
            return true;            
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Properly because you are exiting the function before you are calling the `header();`

Answer (score 2):

Not tested , but I believe the problem is that you have a `return();` before the `header();` so the function is actually exiting before it has a change to change headers ..
try to change

```
} else {        
            return true;            
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
```

to

```
} else {        

            header("Location: index.php");
            return true;        
        }
```

In PHP , a return is actually a command that stops the execution of the function at that specific point ..

Answer (score 1):

remove return true.
You exit your function with the return, so your code never enters the header() :)

Comment: The return makes sense. It just needs to be called after the header-call.

Comment: @HansGerber Not entirely correct as the `return true` can't be counted to be executed before the page is redirected? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @HansGerber Then it's safe to assume that whether leaving the `return true` (after the header) or removing it, would yield the same result?

Comment: The return true is still passed to the code that executed the function even though you called the header-function before.

Answer (score 1):

Place an exit; after header().

Comment: Nothing to do with that, it's simply because he is exiting the function before reaching the `header();`

Comment: if its not reaching the header, it also wont reach the exit :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1) remove the `return true` and set the :

```
else {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

**OR** (and this is the reason for this answer rather than the other good answers here)

you call the function and the set the header once the function returns.

so  code in the function is:

```
else {
        return true;
    }
```

and your function call is:

```
if(sendInvitation($user_email,$invited_by)){
    //function returns true, mail has been sent
    header("location:index.php");
   exit;
 }
```

It is also good practise to put `exit` or `die` statements immediately after a header location redirect to stop the rest of the PHP page being processed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
if(!$mail->Send())
{
    $this->errors[] = 'MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_NOT_SENT'. $mail->ErrorInfo;

}
else
{
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); //redirect to index.php
}
```

Comment: No matter what function you use, the return will keep it from executing. The return needs to come AFTER the header funtion.